# <input type="number"> inconsisent across browsers

Tags: css

I'm having a problem with an `<input type="number">`, here's how it looks in Firefox with no applied CSS:

[image: Firefox]

as you can see, the arrows are higher than the field itself, and there is space between the arrows and the right edge of the field.

In Chromium it looks normal, as it should, the arrows are of the same height as the field and there's no space between the arrows and the right edge.

I have tried to apply height to it, and it grew vertically but not as desired, it grows the same with given 1px or 100px, and it still leaves some space between the arrows and horizontal edges. And when it comes to the redundant space between the arrows and the edge, I didn't know what to try.

How can I overcome the issue so number field in Firefox looks like it does in Chromium? It must look consistent across browsers.

Comment: Aside from essentially reimplementing it from scratch, you don't.

Comment: "It must look consistent across browsers" is not going to be possible without implementing the entire graphics stack yourself. Different OSes have very different paradigms for displaying various inputs, and on OSes like Linux, you can have a variety of different themes.

Comment: I don't have issues with arrow graphics, my problem is the height and redundant space between the arrows and the field edges. I can't believe this is happening in 2019.